# Abrir cliente de email com ficheiro de anexo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou a tentar abrir o meu cliente de email (por exemplo o Outlook) com o seguinte:

```
<a href="mailto:name1@rapidtables.com?subject=Assundo email&body=Corpo de email">
Send mail</a>
```

Agora queria enviar um anexo pelo `mailto`. Já vi que não é possível com a função `mailto`, mas existe outra maneira de abrir o meu cliente de email com um ficheiro anexo?

Answer (score 0):

O protocolo "mailto" não oferece este recurso, principalmente por se tratar de locais e pode variar de dispositivo pra dispositivo. A nível de "Javascript" também não é possível por questões de segurança e incapacidade de comunicar com o sistema operacional para obtenção de arquivos. Uma alternativa seria ao invés de chamar o protocolo "mailto", você disponibilizar na página o upload do arquivo e após a conclusão do envio chamar a função que dispara o e-mail, no caso se for o PHP, a função "mail".

Comment: Sim, mas o objectivo é o anexo passar para o cliente de email. Obrigado

Comment: Isso mesmo @pc_oc, você perguntou uma outra maneira e citei na resposta. A forma que conheço até hoje seria você fazer isso no lado servidor. Via Javascript não há como anexar um arquivo direto chamado o protocolo "mailto".

Comment: Veja se este tópico em inglês pode lhe ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195111/c-sharp-mailto-with-attachment